# PHPUnit + Sonarqube exported coverage do not match with actual xml result

Tags: phpunit, sonarqube

sonarqube: 5.1.2
sonar-runner: 2.2.1
php plugin: 2.6
PHPUnit 4.2.6

We're running phpunit over our application but I'm not able to get the correct coverage % on sonar as expected.

In my phpunit.xml we have filters defining folders that we only want to cover.

```
<whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">
            <directory>./site-library-php/src/main/php/BabelCentral/Model/Content</directory>
        </whitelist>
```

In my sonar properties

```
sonar.modules=php-module
php-module.sonar.phpUnit.coverage.analyzeOnly=true
php-module.sonar.phpUnit.analyzeOnly=true
php-module.sonar.php.tests.reportPath=site-main-php/src/test/target/reports/phpunit.xml
php-module.sonar.php.coverage.reportPath=site-main-php/src/test/target/reports/phpunit.coverage.xml
```

Viewing the log on jenkins, tests seem to run fine and ends with:

```
Tests: 1479, Assertions: 4165, Failures: 58, Incomplete: 14, Skipped: 55.

Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
// further down
11:47:51.973 INFO  - Analyzing PHPUnit test report: site-main-php/src/test/target/reports/phpunit.xml with org.sonar.plugins.php.phpunit.PhpUnitResultParser@35e7e715
11:47:52.604 INFO  - Analyzing PHPUnit unit test coverage report: site-main-php/src/test/target/reports/phpunit.coverage.xml with PHPUnit Unit Test Coverage Result Parser
```

All seems to be working well. However, sonar would report a different result, covering the entire source folder. These are the number shown on the dashboard.

```
Unit Tests Coverage 1.8%
line coverage 1.8%
Unit test success 95.9%
```

Is there anyway to have sonar respect phpunit's configured filter?

Note:
I'm able to achieve the desired numbers on coverage if I explicitly set

```
php-module.sonar.sources
```

to the directories/files that I want. It's just that, comma-separated config is hard to manage than phpunit's xml config.

Comment: You would notice that I also exported coverage in html format - this is for developer use, so we can see how much we're actually covering when we run it in our local machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the set of source files which should be analysed by SonarQube is crucial: it's on this set of files that coding rules are applied and that metrics are computed.
`sonar.sources` is therefore a mandatory property and is the main way to configure the set of source files.

Other properties may be used to refine the set of source files:

- You may configure `sonar.tests`: test files are automatically excluded from `sonar.sources`.
- You may have to exclude some other PHP files like dependencies or generated code with `sonar.exclusions`.

You should also be aware that several plugins may contribute to the global coverage of the project: if you installed the JavaScript plugin and if `sonar.sources` contains JavaScript files, they will also be taken into account when calculating the coverage metrics.

If you're only interested in adjusting coverage, you can exclude files from coverage metrics with `sonar.coverage.exclusions`.

Comment: Yeah.. I figured sonar properties was the only way.
I'ts just hard to manage comma separated config.

Is there a way to to have a feature request to allow arrays?

Something like:

sonar.sources[]=src/modules
sonar.sources[]=src/models
sonar.sources[]=src/helpers

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how such a configuration would be easier to manage.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I wasn't clear.

I just think it's harder to keep track. But this is probably unique for my case. You see, we're in the process of migrating code to a more test driven style, and right now we only want to focus coverage on 14 files/folders.

I guess we'll just have to go with comma-separated config. This should be less of a pain when more and more code is testable and we are able to reduce the config.

Marking this as answer. Thanks.